# wp_enqueue_script and wp_register_script in theme not working

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to use a self written script for the jQuery library in my self-made theme, but it's not working. When I simply use script-tags, everything is alright. So it has to be something with wp_enqueue_script and wp_register_script.
In the beginning of my code in the index.php I have

```
<?php
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'my_name', 'path/to/my/script/script.js'));
    wp_enqueue_script('my_name');
?>
```

I know that normally that has to be written BEFORE wp_head(); but because I am still developing everything, I haven't split my code into various files, I am working straight in the index.php. Do I have to do any other steps before enqueueing the scripts?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_3810' );
function wpse_3810() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'my_name', 'path/to/my/script/script.js'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_name' );
}
```

Comment: Yes, but technically, no *earlier* than `init`. Using `wp_enqueue_scripts` is probably more *semantically* correct.

Comment: Doing enqueue on `init` is wrong and myth, long propagated by incorrect info in Codex. `wp_enqueue_scripts` is correct hook to use for that.

Comment: Oh, good to know. I've changed the code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'wp_enqueue_scripts' hook for this, 'init' is usually not the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you put your code in `functions.php` as that would be loaded before your `index.php`

You should also define dependencies so that they are loaded in the correct order.

```
<?php
//wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
wp_register_script( 'my_name', 'path/to/my/script/script.js', array('jquery') );
?>
```

See: [wp register script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)